# Using Apache mod rewrite to modify a query string

Tags: apache, perl, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I know it is possible to use mod rewrite in my htaccess

Take:

```
http://example.com/directory/perlscript.pl?base64encodedquery=jhfkjdshfsdf78fs8y7sd8
```

Make a shorter URL:

```
http://example.com/? whatever just want to make it prettier
```

Incoming: I am using `use CGI;` thus `$qry->param('base64encodedquery'));` 
Then I use `use MIME::Base64` to decode the query string (encoded previously).

I don't really need to encode and decode the query but, I am learning and just want to mask / hide my query string that contains up to 15 short parameters.

I am leaning towards a Perl module that shortens URLs and I am actively searching. I actually don't think my encoded query can be used with mod rewrite. so I will also take module suggestions as well.

Comment: What is generating the URLs?

Comment: Currently, my script queries my db from a query string that is hard coded or just pasted in my browser because I have not gotten past this long URL issue. Once I get this figured out, I will just make a search form which I have done many times but, not with so many vars. So, I can implement at the source of the query as well if need be.

Comment: A question should not be down voted after it is edited to the point of not representing what I was trying to ask. The question above is not just what I was trying to get at. Oh well, I will refrain from asking any more questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're intending to use generate the requests to your perl script using a HTML form at some point, that lends itself to a very simple solution. You can tell the browser to make a HTTP POST request instead of the usual HTTP GET request by adding a `method` attribute to the form tag like this.

```
<form method="POST" action="http://example.com/directory/perlscript.pl">
<input name="whatever"/>
</form>
```

The browser will make the request to "http://example.com/directory/perlscript.pl", but there won't be a query string - instead the form data is passed in via STDIN. But you don't really need to know that as whatever framework you're using should transparently handle that and provide access to the passed in parameters exactly the same as if they were passed in via the URL.

Comment: Excellent!! THANK YOU Chris. I don't know how that escaped my thought process, lack there of I guess or too close to see? That will work for forms and if I have to send a publicly visible query directly from a script for some reason, I can always write a workaround using POST.  Thank you so much. The mod rewrite still baffles me however, glad I don't need to use it for now. Have a GREAT DAY.

Comment: LWP::UserAgent  is yet again my friend! SOLVED.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear what you need to do, but if you just want to remove the path and query from a URL then you can use the
[`URI`](https://metacpan.org/pod/URI) module

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

use URI;

my $url = URI->new('http://example.com/directory/perlscript.pl?base64encodedquery=jhfkjdshfsdf78fs8y7sd8');

say $url;

$url->path("/");
$url->query("");

say $url;
```

#### output

```
http://example.com/directory/perlscript.pl?base64encodedquery=jhfkjdshfsdf78fs8y7sd8
http://example.com/?
```

Comment: That will not pas the query string for processing correct? I am leaning towards Algorithm::URL::Shorten module but, having trouble figuring out how to implement. Generates fine but, cannot figure out how to either write needed file or even perhaps using mysql.

Comment: @Stephanie: No, it explicitly deletes the query, and produces exactly the output you asked for. Can you explain better what you want to do with it?

Comment: I want to take my long url (due to dynamic query string coming from a search form) and shorten it. I wanted to use mod rewrite in my htaccess to do this. Perhaps 14 of the 15 params in the querystring are blank as well.

Comment: P.S. The Algorithm::URL::Shorten module works great even with encoded query which is great for static links but, my misunderstanding was that that module does not solve shortening the url in the landing pages address bar.

Comment: @Stephanie: I'm still unclear about what you're trying to achieve. The edits I made to your question removed no material information. Ah, it appears from the answer you accepted that you were trying to obfuscate the URL query; that wasn't at all clear to me. Note that even with `POST` the parameters are still visible to someone who wants to make the effort to extract them: they're just not visible in the address line.